# how to migrate from biztalk 2002 to biztalk 2006 R2

Tags: migration, biztalk, data-migration, migrate, code-migration

i would like to have step by step instructions on how to migrate from biztalk 2002 to biztalk 2006 R2.

Comment: Its almost certainly not possible.  Some of the artifacts may come over but there will be challenges with those as well most likely.

Answer (score 3):

BizTalk 2000/2002 is completely different to BizTalk 2004 (onwards). The base architecture and concepts are completely different. Even though Microsoft provided some tools intitially to migrate 2000/2002 projects to 2004 I don't think they are effective. You might loose end up lot of time in the conversion, I would rather suggest you to take this opportunity to rearchitecture the solution (I know its not feasible in lot of cases). But if your organisation is thinking about migration, rearchitecture will be better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting one. BizTalk 2002 and 2006 R2 are so vastly different that i am wondering how much benefit would be gained.

What kinds of artefacts are you wanting to update?

Personally, I would spend the time and re-architect the 2002 solution to take advantage of the new features of 2006 R2.